# how to install python rpm package on windows?

Tags: windows, python, rpm

I'd like to be able to

> import rpm

in my python script in Windows, where do I find the install packages for python rpm module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPMs are RedHat Package Manager packages.  They typically contain binaries that have been compiled specifically for an RPM-based Linux distribution such as RedHat, CentOS, Fedora, etc.

More information on RPM at http://rpm.org/

More information on RPM 5 at http://rpm5.org/

The typical RPM package (python-rpm) is painful to install in Windows.  (You'd need to install RPM itself as well in Windows, which may require porting it.)  There is a pure Python implementation of an RPM module called PyRPM available at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrpm/0.3

Comment: I use cygwin RPM, but maybe PyRPM is enough for me for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install python on Windows ?

If yes, you need to install python through msi installer on windows ...

http://www.python.org/download/windows/

You can't install an RPM pacjage on windows :)